# SBT plugin cross-building with dependency on another plugin

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I am facing an issue with a SBT plugin I have written. If you execute the `publishM2` sbt task on a project that using the plugin, the generated Maven POM file contains a dependency of the plugin. How do I prevent this?

I think the cause is the weirdness I am doing [here](https://github.com/theon/xsbt-coveralls-plugin/blob/master/build.sbt#L31):

```
libraryDependencies <+= (CrossBuilding.pluginSbtVersion) {
  case v if v startsWith "0.13" => Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.github.scct" % "sbt-scct" % "0.3-SNAPSHOT", "0.13", "2.10")
  case v if v startsWith "0.12" => Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.github.scct" % "sbt-scct" % "0.3-SNAPSHOT", "0.12", "2.9.2")
}
```

This is in order to depend on another SBT plugin, whilst being able to build the plugin for multiple SBT versions using [sbt-cross-building](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building).

What have I tried?

- Changing `libraryDependencies` to `projectDependencies` in the above snippet
- Adding the scope `% "test"` to the scct dependency in the above snippet

The project won't compile with either of these changes

More details in [this](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri/issues/40) github issue.